# Calculate declination of Galactic N. Pole given obliquity of Ecliptic, rt. ascension of Galactic N. Pole, & angle between Galactic & Ecliptic Pole

Tags: coordinate, positional-astronomy, celestial-mechanics, ecliptic

I’m trying to back-calculate a value in astronomy using spherical trigonometry. (This is not a homework problem, I'm retired).

Using the following formula, where δ = the Declination of the Galactic North Pole in degrees (i.e., the angle between the North Celestial Pole and the Galactic Equator), and

Given that

acos(sin(δ)cos(23.43928°)−sin(192.8583°)cos(δ)sin(23.439289°)) = ~60.2°

where

23.43928°= obliquity of the Ecliptic (tilt of Earth's axis relative to Ecliptic North Pole)

192.8583°= right ascension of Galactic North Pole in degrees

60.18894°= angle between the Galactic and Ecliptic North Poles (or the angle between the Galactic and Ecliptic Planes)

δ= declination of Galactic North Pole using Equatorial Coordinates

Can you solve for δ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the substitutions:
$$
\begin{align}
a &= \cos{23.43928°} \approx 0.9174821
\\b &= \sin{192.8583°}\sin{23.439289°} \approx -0.0885216
\\\theta &= 60.2°
\end{align}
$$

I believe the solution works out this way:

\begin{align}
\arccos(a \sin \delta - b \cos\delta) &= \theta
\\ a \sin \delta - b \cos\delta &= \cos \theta
\\\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \sin(\delta - \arctan(b/a)) &= \cos\theta
\\\sin(\delta - \arctan(b/a)) &= \frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}
\\\delta& =\arcsin\left(\frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\right) + \arctan(b/a)
\end{align}

Plugging in the substituted values gives $\delta = 27.1°$ ,which is the declination of the North Galactic Pole to three significant figures, according to Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Well, that's brilliant if you don't mind me saying so. I've been looking for this calculation for several years.

Comment: Does b = sin 192.8583° sin 23.439289° mean
(sin 192.8583°*sin 23.439289°)?
That's where I'm getting messed up trying to duplicate your calculations.

Comment: @user46620 It means $b=(\sin192.8583°) * (\sin23.439289°) \approx -0.08852$

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how to use MathML, so I had to convert your equation to an Excel-friendly format. I finally got δ = asin(cosθ/(sqrt(a^2+b^2)))+((atan(b/a)))
and plugging in the values of a, b and θ, I got δ = 27.1°. Using a slightly more accurate value of θ (60.19°), I got δ = 27.13°. The declination of the North Galactic Pole in Stellarium is 27°07'41.7" which converts to 27.13°.